# mysqli query doesn't add data in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database called `mkmatchmanager` and it has a table called `warviewer` as you can see below.

[image]

You can see the structure of the table [here](http://prntscr.com/46tynb). I am trying to add a row in this table:

```
 $a= mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","my_mkmatchmanager");

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect";
 }
 mysqli_query($a, "INSERT INTO `my_mkmatchmanager`.`warviewer` (`clan1`, `score1`, `clan2`, `score2`, `table`) VALUES ('test3', '330', 'test4', '241', 'www.mylink.com'");

 mysqli_close($a);
```

This code is included in a file called `salva.php`. This code by the way doens't work because the query doesn't add the data in the table. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You have no error handling. Add that.

Comment: You should always check for query errors and, in case of failure, retrieve the error message.

Answer (score 3):

Put your double quotes after the parentheses...instead of this:

```
mysqli_query($a, "INSERT INTO `my_mkmatchmanager`.`warviewer` (`clan1`, `score1`, `clan2`, `score2`, `table`) VALUES ('test3', '330', 'test4', '241', 'www.mylink.com'");
```

it should be this:

```
mysqli_query($a, "INSERT INTO `my_mkmatchmanager`.`warviewer` (`clan1`, `score1`, `clan2`, `score2`, `table`) VALUES ('test3', '330', 'test4', '241', 'www.mylink.com')");
```

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
mysqli_query($a, "INSERT INTO `my_mkmatchmanager`.`warviewer` (`clan1`, `score1`, `clan2`, `score2`, `table`) VALUES ('test3', '330', 'test4', '241', 'www.mylink.com')");
```

Comment: *"should be*" - Should be what? Plus, you have a missing bracket.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I believe the OP would know what it should be. I don't think detailed spoon-feeding is required. Added the missing bracket - that was a typo. Thanks for letting me know. These are the kinds of error that you look at the code for so long that you cant see what is in plain site. You only need a nudge to the direction where it is wrong. There is no rocket science involved.

Comment: I know we shouldn't be "spoonfeeding", yet it's usually best to give an added explanation as to where the OP's code is failing. Doing that, is not considered "spoonfeeding", but just giving code, is. You're welcome.